# Calling stored procedure and getting the results back

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hey all this is the first time i am calling a stored procedure via vb.net and i would like to make sure i have everything correct before i execute it.

This is my code:

```
Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
Dim intCount As Integer = 0

Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
   Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

   Try
      connection.Open()
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      command.CommandText = "Complete_S_H"
      command.Parameters.Add("@J_ID", SqlDbType.Int)
      command.Parameters.Add("@O_Nbr", SqlDbType.VarChar)
      command.Parameters.Add("@R_Nbr", SqlDbType.VarChar)
      command.Parameters("@theOutput").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

      Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
      Do While dataReader.Read()
         ListView1.Items.Add(Trim(dataReader(0)))
         ListView1.Items(CInt(intCount)).SubItems.Add(Trim(dataReader(1)))
         ListView1.Items(CInt(intCount)).SubItems.Add(Trim(dataReader(2)))
         ListView1.Items(CInt(intCount)).SubItems.Add(Trim(dataReader(3)))
         ListView1.Items(CInt(intCount)).SubItems.Add(Trim(dataReader(4)))
         ListView1.Items(CInt(intCount)).SubItems.Add(Trim(dataReader(5)))
         intCount = intCount + 1
      Loop

      dataReader.Close()
      connection.Close()
   Catch ex As Exception
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
   End Try
End Using
```

The stored procedure returns 6 colums worth of data and i would like to add that data to a listview. I'm not sure i have the correct sytax for doing that but this is what i used in my previous sql code (running a query with, not a stored procedure).

Also, i'm not sure how to go about getting data for the @xxx names above from a textbox? How do i pass the values into the @xxx names from the users textbox?

The MS SQL mangement studio code is this for the the stored procedure:

```
 EXEC [dbo].[Complete_S_H]
@J_ID = 208660,
@O_Nbr = NULL,
@R_Nbr = NULL
```

Two of the passed varibles can be NULL. Only one needs to be filled out in order for it to return data.

Any help would be great!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close.

Couple of notes:

1. You can get a local reference to the list item that was added, which speeds up and cleans up the code
2. Unless you know that the DB values will never be null, you should always test them for DbNull before using them.
3. To use the values from the textbox, you can use [Parameters.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx). I have modified the code to show how.

The alternative is to set the Parameter's .Value property once it is added:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@J_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
```

or

```
command.Parameters("@J_ID").Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
```

Here is a rewrite with these ideas and a bonus loop for setting the subitems (not required):

```
    Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

        Try
            connection.Open()
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.CommandText = "Complete_S_H"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@J_ID", CInt(TextBox1.Text))
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@O_Nbr", TextBox2.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@R_Nbr", TextBox3.Text)
            command.Parameters("@theOutput").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            'command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Do While dataReader.Read()
                Dim oItem As ListViewItem

                oItem = ListView1.Items.Add(Trim(dataReader(0)))

                For nI As Integer = 1 To dataReader.FieldCount - 1
                    If Not dataReader.IsDBNull(nI) Then
                        oItem.SubItems.Add(Trim(dataReader(nI)))
                    Else
                        oItem.SubItems.Add(String.Empty)
                    End If
                Next
            Loop

            dataReader.Close()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
```

Comment: Awesome CT! It worked great with your little tweaks! Thanks! :o)